# Problem with methods when loading resources as a JSON feed

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm having problems using methods such as getResources and addResource when loading resources from a remote script containing a JSON feed.

If the same resources are included as an array it works fine.
Working example:

```
resources: [{"id":"a","title":"Auditorium A"},{"id":"b","title":"Auditorium B","eventColor":"green"}....
```

https://codepen.io/ProbablyTheRealJonas/pen/yLVzEJw

Not working:

```
resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-resources.json?with-nesting&with-colors',
```

https://codepen.io/ProbablyTheRealJonas/pen/BaQwVjY

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has to do with the fact you're trying to add the resource immediately after calling `calendar.render()` - which isn't really a realistic scenario I don't think - but forgetting that loading resources from a remote URL is *asynchronous*.

Therefore it is very likely that it loads the resources from the server *after* you've called addResource and getResources, which is why you don't see anything. (I assume that's what you mean by "not working" and "having problems" - you were very vague about the actual issue.)

If you make an "add resource" button and move the code for addResources and getResources into that, then they work just fine once the button is clicked - because by then the other resources have had chance to load from the server.

e.g.

```
<button type="button" id="addR">Add Resource</button>
```

and

```
  document.getElementById("addR").addEventListener("click", function () {
    calendar.addResource({
      id: "eeeee",
      title: "Room EEEEE"
    });
    var testing = calendar.getResources();
    console.log(testing.length);
  });
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/oNYGOMN

Comment: Very good point. My main objective is to get the number of resources loaded and that's why I'd like to call it right after it's rendered. I could make another Ajax call but would prefer not adding stress on the database. Maybe I can use the Resource Render Hooks...

Comment: Yes I expect you could do that. Or if you implement the resource feed using the [resources as a function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-function) pattern then you can intercept the results and count them before passing to fullCalendar. The disadvantage is you have to implement the AJAX code yourself, but that's a minor issue really.

Comment: Ended up just using the loading option: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/loading